# Lower maximum capacity of external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, blu-ray, resizing

I am attempting to make the maximum size of my seagate hard drive smaller (it is 5TB and I want it to be 2TB). I have a blu ray player that onlys sees 2<=TB drives. I have tried all of the following:
Partitioning using MBR and GUID
Partitioning moving extra space to allocated,
Partitioning with different drive names, and
just using it as it. Each time I get the message that the drive is not compatible, however my smaller drives work. Any help would be grealy appreciated! My Blu ray player is a panasonic dmp-bdt220

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are checking the size of the HDD, so your can't use it.

Either they are creating their own partitions and reject big drives. Or they are just using the first partition and decided users are stupid and it's not worth the trouble to check if the created partition could work.